# Emacs shell: save commit message

Tags: git, shell, vim, emacs

I've started using emacs a few days ago, and I'm facing a problem when using git in the emacs shell (M-x shell). When I 'git commit' or 'git commit --amend', it opens vim to edit and save the commit message. I'm ok with that, but I can't find a way to save and exit vim, since hitting ESC does not trigger vim Normal Mode, and ESC is my emacs metakey.
I tryed changing my git editor to emacs, but it doesn't work either, it seems like emacs shell cannot run emacs, and it doesn't open a new buffer like I thought it would.

```
emacs: Terminal type "dumb" is not powerful enough to run Emacs.
```

Is there a way I can use git command-line (I'd rather not have to use a git front-end client like magit, ...) with the emacs shell ?

Thanks,
Robin

Comment: You can use `<C-o>` to get out of insert mode for a single command so `<C-o>:wq<CR>` or `<C-o>:x<CR>` or `<C-o>ZZ` should do the trick.

Comment: Yep, it does. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting the answer from @romainl in comment since it does what I want:
`<C-o>` to get out of insert mode, `:wq` or `:x` and Enter.

Answer (score 3):

You can change your editor to something more simple, like nano, using

```
git config core.editor nano
```

Or you could just make it no open any editor by putting your message on the command line :

```
git commit --amend -m "My message"
```

Comment: It look like I cannot close nano either using C-x. It triggers emacs commands instead. I'm on OS X btw, don't know if that matter.

Comment: C-x C-x should send an actual C-x to nano.

Answer (score 0):

One other, round-about, way to do this is to use gits abiltiy to use a file as a commit message:

1. before you commit write your commit message (in emacs) in a temporary file
2. commit with: git commit -F temp_file_name
3. erase the file