# How to edit a commit message in emacs inside a terminal?

Tags: git, emacs

I use macOS, Emacs for text editing, and git for version control. If I make a mistake in a commit message, I type

```
git commit --amend
```

By default this opens `vim`. I can set it to Emacs with:

```
 git config --global core.editor "emacs"
```

and this opens the Emacs GUI in addition to the one already running, and runs all the initialization scripts.

How can I edit a commit message with Emacs within the terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options for Emacs are [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Initial-Options.html). You want `-nw` or `--no-window-system` to load Emacs within the terminal and `-q` or `--no-init-file` to bypass init scripts.

So set your git options as:

```
git config --global core.editor "emacs -nw -q"
```

You can also amend a commit message without text editor (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39528255/emacs-shell-save-commit-message)):

```
git commit --amend -m "My message"
```

Comment: Can I also set it into `emacsclient`?

Comment: @alper Yes, see the other answer by Evgenii `emacsclient`. Beforehand, you need to start the server from inside Emacs, e.g. `M-x server-start`, else you'll see `emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to mmorin's comment:

1. No need to start another instance of emacs every time, just use emacsclient. See https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon
2. If your workflow includes Linux, you may set environment variable EDITOR to emacs/emacsclient to edit everything with emacsclient (or 'editor' alternative in Debian based distros).